# How are package maintainers poked to update their package

Tags: package-management

How are package maintainers poked to update their package? Or is the correct question, how is the distribution poked to update a specific package. Internet searches produce tons of stuff that is not relevant as the words just get swallowed up with how users update a specific package on their own system.

Specifically, the astyle package for Ubuntu is at 3.1-3 while the current release of  [Artistic Style](https://astyle.sourceforge.net/) is at  3.4.8.

Comment: by the way, just a heads up, astyle hasn't been upgraded in debian, fedora, [nor any of the other large Linux distros](https://repology.org/project/astyle/versions) aside from Gentoo and Arch. By installing 3.4.8 you *might* be gettings something that few other people use. This might be cool, because it's very up-to-date, full of features you need, and fewer bugs, or it might break your workflow. Personally, I didn't even realize, but I haven't used astyle in a decade; other indenters were just much better, and for adding colorful syntax highlighting, people tend to use `pygments` these days.

Comment: @marcus-m%c3%bcller It supports --style=lisp / --style=python / -A12 which have not found any where else.

Comment: Interesting! Need to read up on these!

Comment: @marcus-m%c3%bcller rationale behind my use of the formatting https://julianlocals.com/ilm/pages/generate.shtml?news#230831

Comment: See, the thing is, this is about aesthetics, and I generally don't judge, and who am I to tell you how to write your code :) But: I don't think that's a good formatting style, because it makes you search for closing brackets, and it gets either special or puts `while` on a separate line in a `do{…}while()`. Regarding adding C++20 support to astyle: I'd rather try to add e.g. a `BracesOnLastLineOfBlock` [option](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) to `clang-format`,which is what most projects (and VSCode out of the box) use these days to format their code base consistently

Comment: @Marcus Müller https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/68251

Answer (score 3):

The `astyle` package in Ubuntu is imported as-is from Debian, where [it has a configuration file](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/astyle/-/blob/master/debian/watch) specifying how to watch for new releases. Unfortunately it filters on specific types of compression, so newer releases aren’t detected (they would show up [on the package tracker](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/astyle), and [on the maintainer’s dashboard](https://udd.debian.org/dmd.cgi?email1=mcy%40lm7.fr)).

The appropriate way to poke the maintainers in such cases is to file a wishlist bug asking for the new version to be packaged. The best tool for this in Debian derivatives is `reportbug`: run

```
reportbug astyle
```

and follow the prompts. (No such bug has [been filed on `astyle`](https://bugs.debian.org/astyle) so you wouldn’t be duplicating anything.)

As a general rule across distributions, if you notice that a package is out-dated, the appropriate course of action is to file a wishlist bug, after checking that there isn’t one already.

Comment: nice, `debian/watch`, that is in principle a nice idea! Good to know; thanks for teaching me.

Answer (score 0):

That depends. For example, fedora/redhat have https://release-monitoring.org/, a network of observers that either go through websites and check for updates, or fetch source code versions from revision systems, or get notified via register hooks from source hosters and the like.

Debian keeps their packages in salsa.debian.org. I don't have an insight into the maintainers of the individual packages get notified about upstream releases, but it stands to reason they could subscribe to similar services. However, that doesn't address why *your* package of interest has not seen updates. Maybe there is a reason! It might be a good idea to look for your package on salsa, and then look through the filed bugs.